# How to get path of resources file?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have added zip file to resources. How can I get that path?

Comment: You need to include more detail in your question, as it is I don't think anyone will be able to figure out what you're asking for.

Comment: I Agree with Dave. Please add more tags.

Comment: GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() may be of help.

Answer (score 3):

The file does not have a path per se. You need to read its contents using the [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) method. You can read this [step by step tutorial](http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing_embedded_resources_u.php).